# MVC razor update record inside jquery dialog

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, razor, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a mvc razor view, this view contains a couple records.Now how can i get record inside jquery dialog for update.I don't get record according by "Route ID" because it is 5 and no data that ID 5.Should i use it for ajax or can i solve this issue not use ajax?

Page details is follow.

**EmployeeDetail.cshtml**

URL : EmployeeDetail/5

```
@model EmployeeCvBank.EmployeeRepository
```

Person    : Irakli Zuradze

Deparment : IT / Software Developer

```
                                                           + Add new education
+------+--------------------------------+----------------+-------------------+
|  ID  |  Education                     |  Graduate      |  Actions          |
+------+--------------------------------+----------------+-------------------+
|  1   |  Batumi University Msc         |  1/7/2012      |  Edit / Delete    |
+------+--------------------------------+----------------+-------------------+
|  2   |  Tbilisi State University Ms   |  25/9/2010     |  Edit / Delete    |
+------+--------------------------------+----------------+-------------------+
```

Edit and Delete action for Education knowledges

```
public ActionResult EditEducation(PersonEducation model)
{
    ...
}

public ActionResult DeleteEducation(int id)
{
    ...
}

public class EmployeeRepository
{
    public Employee Employee {get;set;}
    public Education Education {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with record id 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not wrong you want to modify Educational detail of user having Id 5 ?

There is always a way around

**Steps**

1. Create Hidden field, which will hold your education id on form submit.

   ```
   @Html.Hidden("EducationId")
   ```
2. Add onclick event to 'Edit' link

   ```
   <a href="javascript:PopulateHiddenFieldsBeforeSubmit('@education.id')" >Edit</a>
   <script>
     function PopulateHiddenFieldsBeforeSubmit(educationId)
      {
        $("#EducationId").val(educationId);//prove hidden educationid field with selected value
        document.forms[0].submit();
      }
   ```
3. Decorate Employee post action

   ```
   Public ActionResult EmployeeDetail(EmployeeRepository collection, int EducationId)
   {
     //Now you have desired educationid here
   }
   ```